# (Sender:TObject)

Tags: delphi

What does (Sender:TObject) mean??
As in:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender:TObject);

var
s: Integer;

begin
.....
.....
end;
```

Comment: You should bookmark this site: 
http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/

And this one: Delphi Language Guide WIKI:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Language_Guide_Index

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sender is a reference to the component that fired the event.  In this case, Sender is going to be the button the user clicked which called your Button1Click event.

This is useful when you have several components that call the same event and you need to figure out which component caused the event to be fired.

For instance, you could do something like:

```
if Sender = Button1 then
// ...
```

Comment: @Jeff: you might want to rephrase this as "Sender is a reference to the component". (at the end you could mention that in Win32 the Sender technically is a pointer, but in other environments it does not need to be).

Comment: @Jeroen: Yeah, I'm actually a C++ Builder user.  We share the VCL (Visual Component Library) with Delphi.  So, Sender is a pointer for me.  Thanks for the reminder to translate.

Comment: Actually ... even that isn't 100% accurate since you can pass just about anything as the sender if you want to. The global concencus is that you should use it to send a reference to the Class / Object which triggered the event, but that as such isn't a requirement. I'm not saying it's good practice to pass anything else, but I've seen code where that assumption was made incorrectly. That was an awesome example of bad coding IMHO, but it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sender is a parameter which is often used when triggering events (calling Event Handlers).  Most of the time I would describe it as the Object from which the Event is triggered.

But you could actually pass any object to a Sender parameter as long as it inherits from TObject in this specific case.  As Jim mentioned already, in this specific cast you added an event handler to the OnClick event of Button1.  So when the Button1 gets clicked, the method Tform1.ButtonClick will be executed and the sender will contain a reference to the instance o f the button you clicked.

Regards,

Stefaan

Comment: There is no object that does not inherit from `TObject`.

Comment: Think I expressed myself incorrectly.  You can pass anything in the Sender parameter as long as it's a TObject.