# Sites for beginning Delphi programmers

Tags: delphi

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284070/sendertobject), it might be nice to collect links to sites that really help Delphi beginners.

The first answer pointed to [Delphi Basics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/), which is a really nice site.
But there must be more.

So: please contribute to this community wiki question.

Comment: I guess www.stackoverflow.com doesn't count? ;)

Comment: Then we can refer the Noobs to the "I'm a noob" question. Good idea.

Answer (score 9):

- [A Beginner's Guide to Delphi Programming](http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/delphicourse.htm) (at http://delphi.about.com)
- on-line version of [Teach Yourself Borland Delphi 4 in 21 Days](http://101.lv/learn/delphi/) (still very relevant)
- [Learn To Program Delphi Part One](http://www.bitwisemag.com/2/Learn-To-Program-Delphi-Part-One) (at http://www.bitwisemag.com)
- [Essential Pascal](http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/) (at http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/)

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/269504/balgan I've reformatted your answer to make it better readable.

Comment: Thank you, was kinda of a bit in a rush when I did it :)

Answer (score 4):

What about this ?

- [Delphi wiki](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Wiki)

Comment: It is very difficult to learn the language using the wiki. There is no order, and you feel like you are chasing your tail all the time.

Comment: Well, nevertheless it definitely HELPS beginners. They might have a concrete question or problem.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi.wikia.com has a [Delphi Videos](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Videos) link that was great for me when I was first learning Delphi.

[Nick Hodges 30 Camtasia Demos](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/nickhodges/2006/08/15/26687) are great.

[Alister Christie has great videos](http://LearnDelphi.tv) as well.

Answer (score 2):

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369903/where-are-all-the-delphi-developers): **"Where are all the Delphi Developers?"** you can find a lot of resources, Webs, forums, links,... where you can get help and information to start with Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

In German language:
http://www.delphi-treff.de/

In Dutch language
http://www.nldelphi.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are actually 2 quite good Embarcadero sites that I sometime use.

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Main_Page
- http://channel-e.embarcadero.com/

Hope they help

Answer (score 1):

This guy makes videos, I have had use of them myself:

http://www.youtube.com/user/codegearguru

EDIT: Did not see anyone already posted that, sorry :P

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my site, all my videos can be found on http://LearnDelphi.tv

Answer (score 1):

The [Delphi Foundations](http://delphifoundations.com/) book by Chris Rolliston is very good also.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of recent links to resources, including free training and Starter Editions:

[Getting Started with Delphi](https://glooscapsoftware.blogspot.ca/2017/04/getting-started-with-delphi.html)